# Crash when populating array with image data from disk

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm saving UIImages to disk:

```
let sketchData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sketch)
let sketchPath: String = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents/Sketch\(indexNumber).png")
sketchData.writeToFile(sketchPath, atomically: true)
```

Then, I'm trying to repopulate an array with them:

```
if lengthOfSketchArray > 0 {
    for indexNumber in 0...lengthOfSketchArray {
        let sketchPath: String = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents/Sketch\(indexNumber).png")
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: sketchPath)
        slideSketchArray[indexNumber] = image!
        }
    }
```

On the last line, I'm getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

I've tried a lot of variations but every one crashes. What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

It's working now! I've changed a lot of things based on the comments, including using
 `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, as well as no longer saving images in an array. Now I'm saving the image path, and loading the image from disk when I need it.

```
func saveImageToDisk() {
    let sketchData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sketch)
    let destinationFolder: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let sketchPath: String = "\(destinationFolder)\(currentProjectID).png"
    sketchData.writeToFile(sketchPath, atomically: true)
    let currentMetadata: [String: String] = [
        "sketchpath": sketchPath
    ]
    allMetadata.append(currentMetadata)
    defaults.setObject(allMetadata, forKey: "allMetadata")

func loadImageAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIImage {
    let sketchPath: String = allMetadata[index].objectForKey("sketchpath") as String
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: sketchPath)
    return image!
}
```

Comment: Can you log `sketchPath` each iteration of the loop and post the results?

Comment: You are doing `for indexNumber in 0...lengthOfSketchArray`. Did you mean `..<` rather than `...`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `NSHomeDirectory` and appending to it to find the documents directory.  Rather you should be using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` or `NSFileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSDocumentDirectory, domainMask: .UserDomainMask)`  With iOS 8, the Documents directory is no longer co-located with the application directory.

Comment: BTW, a broader (and unrelated) issue is that loading images into an array is a fairly extravagant use of memory. I'd suggest only retrieving the images from persistent storage when they're actually needed. If you're trying to optimize performance, you might consider using a `NSCache` (which you'll purge upon memory warning) instead of an array.

Comment: Please see my update with working code. I think having the wrong file path was my biggest problem, although likely including the full length of the array was also causing a crash (but I'm no longer populating an array with images, so it's moot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the "closed" range of `0 ... lengthOfSketchArray`, which will include *both* zero and `lengthOfSketchArray` (i.e. you will repeat this `lengthOfSketchArray + 1` times). I think you intended to use a "half-open" range of `0 ..< lengthOfSketchArray`, which will not include `lengthOfSketchArray`, i.e. it will go from zero to `lengthOfSketchArray - 1`:

```
let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

for index in 0 ..< lengthOfSketchArray {
    let path = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Sketch\(index).png")
    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
        slideSketchArray[index] = image
    }
}
```

By the way, I'm using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` to find the Documents folder. You'd obviously use the same technique when saving the images, too.

Also, the above assumes that you've declared and instantiated this array already. For example, if it was a Swift array, e.g.

```
var slideSketchArray = [UIImage]()
```

Comment: It looks like my main problem was having the wrong file path, so there was actually no image in the place I was trying to load from.

Answer (score 0):

'...' in for loop mean that you include lengthOfSketchArray as last value of your iterator. Maybe that why it crash at last value cause it out of your array length. You should use (lengthOfSteckArray-1) or .. instead of ... (I read that in Swift book but I'm not sur 100%). Anyway, you should verify if your optional variable has a value before wrap it to get value. Then, use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains to retrieve path to your Documents folder

```
var documentDir: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    if lengthOfSketchArray > 0 {
        for indexNumber in 0..lengthOfSketchArray {
            let sketchPath: String = documentDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Sketch\(indexNumber).png")
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: sketchPath)
            slideSketchArray[indexNumber] = image!
            }
        }
```